# jquery 'invalid expression' using selector on a tablecell

Tags: jquery

Hi can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong in this jquery statement.
I have a 'row' object which contains any number of tablecells, and i'm looking only for the cells that contain a textbox or text area.

This statement works fine:

```
var $textCells = jQuery('td:has(textarea)', row);
```

but i need to include 'text', inputs, and this is where is blows up:

```
var $textCells = jQuery('td:has(textarea,input[@type=text])', row);
```

I get an 'Unrecognized expression error'.
Can someone set me straight?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jquery are you using? @ for the attribute selector was removed a while ago, as of version 1.3.